# Using double buffering breaks Graphics.PageScale

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics

I have `UserControl` with folowing styles set:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

I have `OnPaint` event handler which sets `Graphics.PageScale` and `Graphics.TranslateTransform()` to set my map position and scale:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    if (Splines == null) return;
    var pens = new[] {
        new Pen(TrackColor),
        new Pen(TrackColor),
        new Pen(RoadColor),
        new Pen(RiverColor),
        new Pen(CrossColor)
    };
    var b = Splines.Bounds;
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.PageScale = _CurrentScale;
    g.TranslateTransform(-b.Left, -b.Top);
    foreach (var s in Splines) {
        if (s.L) g.DrawLine(pens[s.T], s.A, s.D);
        else g.DrawBezier(pens[s.T], s.A, s.B, s.C, s.D);
    }
    foreach (var p in pens) p.Dispose();
}
```

Without double buffering it works as expected, but very slow. With double buffering it doesn't work at all, I get only background.

When I disable `Graphics.TranslateTransform()` - I get unscaled map drawn. Like `Graphics.PageScale` was ignored.

What am I missing? Are these methods not allowed with double buffering? So what should I do? Scale and translate my map manually, by scaling and translating each data point? It could defeat most speed gain from double buffering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Scale and translate my map manually, by scaling and translating each data point? It could defeat most speed gain from double buffering.

You can scale the map outside the paint handler (every time you recalculate the view); that shouldn't cause too much a performance hit, especially if you use integers rather than floats.
Integer multiplication is very fast.

Comment: I've done scaling and translating "manually" inside `OnPaint` (to save memory) and it's fast enough for now. Basicaly `OnPaint` in double buffered mode is called only after `Invalidate` and `Invalidate` is called when let's say - control size is changed, which requires scaling and translating to be recalculated. I'm impressed how fast WinForms can draw 2D graphics.